# Document library user group restriction

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-online

I have a document library where users from two different groups(group_1, group_2) has access.

The document library contain various file types `.docx, .xls, .pdf`. What I want to do is I want group_2 user to access files with `.pdf` extension. I don't want group_2 users to access other file types than pdf:s.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this. You should look for "Item Based Security". You can find a similar problem here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b0b20e7c-f5d8-4561-9d9e-9bfdf09e1d9d/how-to-give-item-level-permission-based-on-field-in-sharepoint-list